# Rails 3: link_to and image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, hyperlink

How can I have an image tag linking to the file `background.jpg` in my public/images and when clicked on redirect the user to the root_url (So the content of the page is in a container and if the user clicks on the background image are redirected to home?) Thanks!

Comment: if one of the answers solves your dilemma, please accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

Sure:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("background.jpg", :alt => "home image", :width => 100, :height => 100, :title => "Click here to return to Home") "/") %>
```

Comment: When you do this, the link does not stretch vertically to fill the screen even though the image does. So if you click in the top few pixels of the browser window you are redirected but if you click anywhere else you are not. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Just added in width and height to show you.  However, that sure sounds like the CSS for the areas around the link has issues.

Comment: Solution does satisfy the question. I say we pay no attention to the CSS behavior as it's beyond the scope of this discussion.

Answer (score 7):

Most of rails tag helpers accept a block, which means you can use `do` to simplify your life. Here I use a block with `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to root_url do %>
  <%= image_tag "background.jpg" %>
<% end %>
```

In this case, link_to expects the next parameter to be the path and the block emits what the anchor wraps.

In general I try to keep to the *one tag helper per line* rule unless its super trivial, so  prefer this technique when the line would otherwise become crowded. An advantage to doing it this way is since tags are on different lines, errors are easier to identify.

If you need other options to go with it, add them like you usually would. For example I'll add a css class:

```
<%= link_to root_url, :class => 'imagelink' do %>
  ...
```

Answer (score 4):

I was searching for same thing while ago, and i found the Rails way to do so.

Lets say you want to you HTML page to render follwoing code

```
<a title="Return Home" class="logo" href="/pages/home">
 <img width="200" height="50" src="logo.png" alt="Logo Image">
</a>
```

Where 'pages' is the controller and 'home' is the action. Here's the Rails way.

```
    <%=link_to(image_tag("12roots-logo.png",:size => "209x50", :alt=> "12roots"),
 {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}, :title=>"Return Home", :class=>"logo") %>
```